# How to useState on a set of mapped <input> elements

Tags: reactjs, state, apollo-client, gql

I built a day planner that allows users to add days to a travel plan and add activities to a day. I have created Apollo client mutations and queries so users can add days by clicking a button and clicking another button to query all the days added into the database.

Right now I have a problem **using states on these mapped days** since I cannot use for loops to set states for these mapped "days" and I can't find a solution anywhere. How should I solve this problem? (Currently, the mapped elements of the same time share the **same state** and I cannot update a specific day **individually**)

**The mapped days that the user decides to create and input for the different times**:

```js
return (
        <div className="container">
            <button onClick={handleAddDay}>Add Day</button>
            <button onClick={handleFetch}>Check Day</button>
            <div>
            {planData ? planData.singlePlan.days.map((days) => {
                return (
                    <div className="text-left">
                        <h2>Day {days.dayNumber + 1} </h2>
                        <form>
                            <label>9am: </label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange1} value={dayInfo1}></input>
                            <br></br>
                            <label>12am: </label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange2} value={dayInfo2}></input>
                            <br></br>
                            <label>3pm: </label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange3} value={dayInfo3}></input>
                            <br></br>
                            <label>6pm: </label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange4} value={dayInfo4}></input>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                )
            }) : ('No Data yet')
            }
            </div>
            <button>Rock and Roll!</button>
            <h1>Number of days: {day}</h1>
            
        </div>
    )
```

**The use states are defined here:**

```js
    //text from 9am
    const [dayInfo1, setdayInfo1] = useState();
    const handleChange1 = (event) => {
        setdayInfo1(event.target.value);
    };
    //text from 1pm
    const [dayInfo2, setdayInfo2] = useState();
    const handleChange2 = (event) => {
        setdayInfo2(event.target.value);
    };
    //text from 3pm
    const [dayInfo3, setdayInfo3] = useState();
    const handleChange3 = (event) => {
        setdayInfo3(event.target.value);
    };
    //text from 5pm
    const [dayInfo4, setdayInfo4] = useState();
    const handleChange4 = (event) => {
        setdayInfo4(event.target.value);
    };
```

[The form at the front end after I created 5 days.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTKfK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think tou need to do your form as component with this useStates. And I recommend you to use object in state, then you only need one function to manage your form.

```
const [dayInfo, setdayInfo] = useState({
    9: '',
    12: '',
    3: '',
    6: '',
});

const handleChange = (event, fieldToUpdate) => {
    setdayInfo(prevState => {
        ...prevState,
        [fieldToUpdate]: event.target.value
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I do agree the object in the state works much more efficiently. Regarding the form as a component, this whole add-day template already is a component, what difference would it make in terms of how the individual days are tracked if I drill another component for the form?

Comment: the difference is that your useState and handleChange will refer specifically to the form component in which they are located, and now you have one state for all forms. Make a form component where this useState and handleChange will be, then render it through a map for each day